# npm install result in an incomplete module, but yarn install is successful, why they behave differently?

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I tried `npm install` and `npm install --no-optional` for my forked repository, and it was not installed completely: `git+https://github.com/marsonmao/react-sketch#v0.4.104` ([link](https://github.com/marsonmao/react-sketch/releases/tag/v0.4.104)).

After using npm install, only part of the repository was installed: there are only `/node_modules` and `.eslintrc`, `karma.config.js`, `README.md`...etc in `MyProject/node_modules/react-sketch`, but no `/lib` and `/src`...etc.

Then I tried `yarn install` and it was successful, every file in the repository was installed.

So why npm failed however yarn succeeded?

npm version: 5.5.1, yarn version: 1.3.2